# Select distinct rows with max count another row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

help please. I need to get each date the maximum value of the Count column.

```
| id | date       | count |
| 1  | 2022-01-01 | 2     |
| 2  | 2022-01-01 | 3     |
| 3  | 2022-01-02 | 4     |
| 4  | 2022-01-02 | 7     |
```

expected result:

```
| id| date        | count |
|2  | 2022-01-01  |3      |
|4  | 2022-01-02  |7      |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to order the rows in each group (in your case one group is defined by unique date) starting with the row with highest count. Then, we are using the `TOP 1 WITH TIES` to get only rows with ROW_NUMBER = 1:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempTable;

CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
    id INT,
    date DATE,
    count INT
);

INSERT INTO #tempTable (id, date, count)
VALUES
    (1, '2022-01-01', 2),
    (2, '2022-01-01', 3),
    (3, '2022-01-02', 4),
    (4, '2022-01-02', 7);

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM #tempTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY count DESC)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get each date for the maximum value of the Count column.

In SQL-Server 2012; You can do it using correlated subquery [as in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y6Mqh5ai)

```
SELECT id, date, count
FROM table_name t1
WHERE count = (
  SELECT MAX(count)
  FROM table_name t2
  WHERE t1.date = t2.date
)
order by id;
```

Output :

```
id    date            count
2     2022-01-01      3
4     2022-01-02      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL sample in a very simple way, you don't need to use DISTINCT instead you should use GROUP BY then add some COUNT.

MySQL

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count

FROM table_name
GROUP BY day;
```

Here is the result
[SQL imgage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiRDE.png)
I hope it helps!

SQL-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
date DATE NOT NULL,
count INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_name (id, date, count)
VALUES (1, '2022-01-01', 2),
   (2, '2022-01-01', 3),
   (3, '2022-01-02', 4),
   (4, '2022-01-02', 7);

SELECT CONVERT(date, date) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, date);
```

Output

[day    count
2022-01-01  2
2022-01-02  2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn9f3.png)

Comment: `GROUP BY day` You can't use `GROUP BY` on a column alias.

Comment: Are you really sure? You can check the SQL image that I attached, it is working

Comment: That probably works on `MySQL` but not `SQL Server`. OP tagged `SQL Server 2012`

Comment: My apology, I didn't check the tag, you can check it now